# Are religions (generally) inducing fear in humans in the name of hell to make them believe in God?

Tags: sin, naraka

There are different kinds of pleasures and pains both physical and mental pain and there are also various tastes like sweet, sour, hot etc., Some like sweet and some are allergic to sweet (which may even cause death) like wise, *Mostly in this world people enjoy physical pleasure and their are fear of physical pain. But there are some kind of people who enjoys physical pain (masochist - a person who enjoys pain) and hates pleasures. If all the punishments are going to be given from Garuda Purana in this world for the masochist he is really going to enjoy every punishments given to him like in heaven.* This does make the sense that pain and pleasures are different tastes. So why does hell chose a particular taste("Pain") just because people are feared of it and they will believe in religion?

**Forever theory of hell and heaven** Hinduism is good in this part (re-incarnations). I do not accept some religions saying Hell is forever. One cannot be punished forever for 1-1xx years of his/her life span. I appreciate this concept here. So no more question here. *I am not comparing Religion X with Hinduism.*

**THE PRIME SIN**
Here I include all religions (including Hinduism) but not limiting/comparing/complaining one religion with another.

The prime sin in most of the religions is itself, **Not believing their own God**. Say there are X religions in the world and I belong to Hinduism and I do believe in God (Yes I believe in all Hindu Gods). So this makes me a non-believer of **X-1** religions. So, Do I need to suffer in X-1 hells? this makes no sense. How Hinduism address this? If somebody (not-be so don't blame) says Hinduism is the only religion, take another person with different religion does he need to suffer in our hell just because he trusted the wrong God?

Comment: I think its just better to ask only about Hinduism. Because "Are religions induce fears in the name of hell to make them believe in god " is a kind of general question related to all religions  and then will be ideal for   Philosophy stack exchange.

Comment: Do u expect the scriptures to say that there are no hells in truth and just to frighten the humans their existences have been imagined?

Comment: @Rickross, I am expecting an explanation to teach me :) I don't understand the hell theory. Actually I wanted to know the survival guide in Kali Yuga but some people have closed question too broad. but I know befrore itself and backed up my text :) https://pastebin.com/QmTFihx8

Comment: Can ur Q be put into one or two lines? :) Is it ok that we answer after reading just  the post title? :D @VISWESWARANNAGASIVAM

Comment: @Rickross, As long as I learn this, I am fine :)

Comment: `do's` and `don't's` also related to `hell` and `heaven` I thought.

Comment: This Hi SE website is not about religions, but is about one religion - Hinduism. Try to stick to the topic because your question might be closed.

Answer (score 3):

Disbelief in God does not lead to hell according to Hinduism.

Gita acknowledges the right of a person to reject its teachings.

> ‘..Reflecting on this entire teaching, do as you think fit.’

*Gita 18.63*

**Gita's description of atheists.**

> According to them nothing is ultimately real in this world. It is
>   Godless and without any moral basis. Being born of sex union, what
>   else but lust can be said to be its cause?

*Gita 16.8*

**What happens to atheists?**

> These vicious men, oppressive, cruel and sinful as they are, - are
>   always **hurled down by Me into demoniac wombs in life after life, in
>   the transmigratory cycle**.

Gita 16.19

Atheists would remain in Samsara, the cycle of birth and death, since they will not do spiritual practice to purify their hearts and know God and will thus suffer. Atheists wil not go to hell.

> **The only way to end of sorrow is to know God**.When men shall roll up
>   space as if it were a piece of leather, then will there be an end of
>   sorrow, apart from knowing God.

*Svetasvatara Upanishad VI.20*

Knowing God and not belief is necessary to escape from the eternal cycle of samsara.

The discussion about the various hells in the Garuda Purana is designed to stop people from doing bad things and not to scare them to believe in God.